# Pandas: Save Dict/Json using python

Tags: pandas, azure-blob-storage

Following is the code I used to store dataframe as csv into Azure blob in python.

```
    output = df.to_csv(index_label="idx", encoding="utf-8")

    blob_service.create_blob_from_text('test', folderName + 'abc.csv', output)
```

Is there any way to store python dictionary as json the similar way as above?

Essentially I want to get the 'output' object of dict to_json.

Comment: convert your data to json and then save it to json ????

Comment: ya I have my dict in Json. how should I save it in Blob then? What would be the command?

Comment: `create_blob_from_text` is fine, check the documentation otherwise https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/

Comment: I am aware that create_blob_from_text will be used but I dont know how to get the 'output' variable of the json. output = df.to_csv(index_label="idx", encoding="utf-8") How to get this for json?

Comment: Sorry I dont know. You should update your question and tag it as a panda data frame question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your python `dict` to `json` string using this:

```
import json

output = json.dumps(your_dict_here)
```

And then you can store it just like before:

```
blob_service.create_blob_from_text('test', folderName + 'abc.json', output)
```